# What is the default transaction attribute type of an EJB 2 session bean container managed persistence?

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

I'm migrating an application from `EJB2` to `EJB3`, In a CMP session the transaction attributes are not defined so i'm wondering if there is any default attribute being used. I know that in `EJB3` the default transaction attribute is **Required**.

Here is how the session bean is defined in the ejb-jar.xml :

```
<session>
      <ejb-name>FileFacade</ejb-name>
      <home>file.FileFacadeHome</home>
      <remote>file.FileFacade</remote>
      <ejb-class>file.FileFacadeBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
<session>
```

Comment: EJB3 inherited its default behaviour from EJB2

Comment: So all methods defined in FileFacade have transaction type attribute Required ?

Comment: That is correct